# Special Permissions on task

Tags: tasks

I'm having a problem with 'SpecialPermissions' its underlined in red (last line of code)

Error 1 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowTaskProperties' does not contain a definition for 'SpecialPermissions' and no extension method 'SpecialPermissions' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowTaskProperties' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
using System.Collections.Specialized;

private void FC_RemovePendingTask_MethodInvoking(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FC_RemovePendingTask_TaskId1 = Guid.NewGuid();
    FC_RemovePendingTask_TaskProperties1.Title = "Remove Timer";

    FC_RemovePendingTask_TaskProperties1.DueDate = DateTime.Today;

    FC_RemovePendingTask_TaskProperties1.AssignedTo = "S_Financial";



    HybridDictionary permsCollection = new HybridDictionary();

    permsCollection.Add(FC_RemovePendingTask_TaskProperties1.AssignedTo, SPRoleType.Administrator);   

    FC_RemovePendingTask_TaskProperties1.SpecialPermissions = permsCollection;
 }
```

Comment: Raj, no need to use `<pre>` tag in the code formatting. Using the `{}` button will format it properly and apply color coding.

Answer (score 1):

It's [CreateTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflowactions.createtask) itself that has [SpecialPermissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflowactions.createtask.specialpermissions) not [SPWorkflowTaskProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkflowtaskproperties) so you should set in to the CreateTask activity using the taskproperties

Comment: I've tried setting it in the tasp properties now. Clicking on special permissions a dialog box pops up but there are no members to select from? How can i add members ? Thanks

Comment: As far as I know you can'd do it in the UI. But in your code you just reference `createTask1.SpecialPermissions` (Where `createTask1` is the name of your activity) instead of `FC_RemovePendingTask_TaskProperties1.SpecialPermissions`